# How to get subcollections and your documents in Firestore/Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this Structure in my db:

```
    videos (C)
    - iajsdojasfio (D)
    -- name : "hello" (string)
    -- url : "http.." (string)
    - Folder (D)
    -- FolderNameChoosed (C)
    --- jsadiujaf (D)
    ---- name: "videoName" (string)
    ---- url: "url" (string)
    others
```

How can I get the items from all the collections inside 'Folder' document? Or get the name of the collections to subsequent query

This is what i'm trying now:

```dart
await databaseReference
  .collection("videos")
  .doc("Folder")
  .get()
});
```

But in this way I don't have the option to do the forEach in the snapshot... How can I handle that? Is It possible?

(D) : Document

(C) : Collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot get a specific document and in the **same** query get all the documents from it's one (or several) subcollections.

So either:

- get a specific document
- get documents from a collection/subcollection
- get documents from all subcollections of same name (collectionGroup query)